# Where does HERE get their data from?

Tags: here-api

Especially their photos.

I'm asking because I want to make a website similar to Yelp, on which people can search for restaurants in any city. I contacted Yelp to use their API, but I was told "This seems too align with Yelp, so this doesn't seem to be a good use to case to utilize our API."

So if the HERE photos are from Yelp, that might be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the regions. You can request the meta info over the MapTile service itself. Further details are in the documentation available:
https://developer.here.com/documentation/map-tile/dev_guide/topics/tile-metainfo.html

The following provisions apply to the use of Satellite Imagery:

1. Satellite Imagery is made available for online use and viewing only and may not be downloaded or otherwise extracted for offline use in any capacity.
2. All use and display of Satellite Imagery must include the following copyright notice: ©20XX DigitalGlobe or ©CNES 2015, Distribution Airbus DS; © 2015 DigitalGlobe